# How to disable autocorrection for sudo [command] in zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, autocorrection

I have zsh and oh-my-zsh with default values and can't figure out how to turn off autocorrection for specific commands, that I often use, such as: sudo mc or sudo gem update. The thing is that I have `.mc` directory and `.gem` directory and zsh proposes autocorrections (`zsh: correct 'mc' to '.mc' [nyae]`).

Generally I would like to config zsh so that `sudo [smth]` is not considered a separate command (which it is not) for autocorrection. What would be a fix for that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`

```
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'
```

Comment: That was simple! :)

Comment: this should be a standard setting in zsh