# sudo: nocorrect: command not found

Tags: zsh, alias, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh and oh-my-zsh on Arch Linux. I am not able to make directory using `mkdir`

```
edward@ArchLinux  ~ $ sudo mkdir -p /samba/raspberry
  [sudo] password for edward: 
  sudo: nocorrect: command not found
```

I know it has to do something with auto-completion feature of zsh and alias defined but can't figure out.

Comment: I don't know a thing about zsh, but it's possible that the contents of your .zshcompdump file would help diagnose the issue

Comment: What is the output of `alias | grep sudo=`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have this alias `alias sudo='sudo '`defined in a file which I `source`d at the end of `~/.zshrc` file which overwrote `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'` which is defined in `.oh-my-zsh/lib/correction.zsh`

`alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'` is required by zsh's auto-completion feature to work
More: [How to disable autocorrection for sudo [command] in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-to-disable-autocorrection-for-sudo-command-in-zsh)

But at same time I need `alias sudo='sudo '` for aliases of commands following `sudo` to work
More: [Load aliases from .bashrc file while using sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235366/load-aliases-from-bashrc-file-while-using-sudo)
**Please note `alias sudo='sudo '` works for zsh too**

So I can either have zsh's auto-completion feature or have aliases (of other commands) while using `sudo` so I have now disabled zsh's auto-completion feature.

(*Hope I am clear and not confusing.*)

Comment: I am not familiar with `zsh`  but there is probably a `'` missing.

Comment: You don't, just use `sudo \mkdir ...` to disable alias expansion for `mkdir`.

Comment: @cuonglm it turns out that the problem is due to `alias mkdir='nocorrect mkdir'`, why?

Comment: `alias sudo='sudo '` make alias expansion for `cmd` when you use `sudo cmd`. `sudo mkdir` expand to `sudo nocorrect mkdir`, which cause the error, because `nocorrect` is a reserved work. `sudo \cmd` disable alias expansion for `cmd`.

Comment: @cuonglm yes, your idea is can be a second choice along with mine, either disable auto-correction or use \ with every command that have alias of the type `alias command='nocorrect command'`. You should add this in answers

Comment: Another idea would be to wrap mkdir in a script, with something like follows: `if [ $(whoami) = root ]; then mkdir $@; else nocorrect mkdir $@; fi`.

Comment: This is all very frustrating. Commands should not have completely different behavior because they are run with sudo first. Aliases should just work with sudo. Auto-correction should either be enabled or disabled, and should still work with sudo. Making the behavior change is just bringing in inconsistency and thus inviting trouble. To make things worse, they piled more bad stuff on top of these bad things. Even if auto-correction would not affect anything, sometimes it still needs to be disabled. Of course this has nothing to do with the answer posted here... I guess I should create issues.

Comment: I thought that maybe if I completely disable autocorrection using `unsetopt correct_all` and `unsetopt correct` that I could use the sudo alias `alias sudo='sudo '` that makes it work with aliases and have it still work with commands like mdkir, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to answer from @edward-torvalds,

In your .aliases file, the use of a Tab might not be visible enough for some.  Your alias definition can be written as such for better reading:

```
alias sudo=$'nocorrect sudo\t'
```

---

However, I did have issues with a trailing **space**, but not a trailing **tab**.

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '
```

above aliases resulted in errors, as follows:

```
~$ which mkdir 
mkdir: aliased to nocorrect mkdir -p -pv

~$ which sudo
sudo: aliased to nocorrect sudo

~$ alias sudo                  
sudo='nocorrect sudo '

~$ sudo mkdir /tmp/foo
sudo: nocorrect: command not found
```

---

Therefore, this would work `alias sudo='sudo       '`

but I prefer `alias sudo=$'nocorrect sudo\t'`
in a 1K+ line zshrc, the latter is just too simple ;)

...if anyone can possibly say why, please comment!

Comment: Why do you believe that there should be a tab in the alias at all?

Comment: The tab (or space) after the alias is explained well in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/22043)

Answer (score 0):

A trick to make `alias sudo='sudo '` work with `nocorrect` aliases would be to create this small `nocorrect` script in your path:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
exec "$@"
```

This will make `nocorrect` a noop for sudo.